# How to write something after the user's input when using Node.js `readline`

Tags: node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

Say I want to ask the user a question in a CLI interface, then they type in an answer and press return.

I want to show a tick or a cross next to their answer.

How can I do this using `readline`?

Thoughts:

- Listen for `process.stdin.on 'keypress', ->` and use ascii control codes to move the cursor back to end of previous line. Not sure this will work unless there is a way to cancel the keypress event.
- Cancel the key press somehow <- not sure this is possible.
- Maybe I have to create my own `readline` module by listening to keypress?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's easy enough to move backward within a line, but moving to the previous line is weird.  You may need https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses or https://github.com/chjj/blessed